# Replace Abstract Class with Interface

Tags: php, class

I'm working on forking an existing MVC PHP application and all normal page controllers are extended from controller.

`class MyController extends Controller`

The controller class is an abstract class with 2 magic methods, `__set` and `__get` and a constructor `__construct`

```
abstract class Controller {
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
        return $this->registry->get($key);
    }

    public function __set($key, $value) {
        $this->registry->set($key, $value);
    }
}
```

I've searched all through the entire application and nowhere are `__get` or `__set` ever called manually. So I have to assume that these methods are indeed magical and are doing something with the registry that isn't available to see.

Dispatching is done through the Front class which already holds the registry as an object:

```
final class Front {
    private $registry;
    private $pre_action = array();
    private $error;

    public function __construct($registry) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function addPreAction($pre_action) {
        $this->pre_action[] = $pre_action;
    }

    public function dispatch($action, $error) {
        $this->error = $error;
        foreach ($this->pre_action as $pre_action):
            $result = $this->execute($pre_action);
            if ($result):
                $action = $result;
                break;
            endif;
        endforeach;

        while ($action):
            $action = $this->execute($action);
        endwhile;
    }

    private function execute($action) {
        $result = $action->execute($this->registry);

        if (is_object($result)):
            $action = $result;
        elseif ($result === false):
            $action = $this->error;
            $this->error = '';
        else:
            $action = false;
        endif;

        return $action;
    }
}
```

My thought was that replacing the abstract class Controller with an Interface would be a better solution, but I'm unsure about what these magic methods are actually doing.

How can I tell if I can/should make this change?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you simply don't know what `__get` and `__set` do? http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get

Comment: `replacing the abstract class Controller with an Interface would be a better solution` -- what is the issue?

Comment: No I understand the set and get to unavailable properties, I don't know what they are setting and getting to the registry specifically in my app, and if it would be safe/practical convert this to an interface.

Comment: An interface only contains method signatures (abstract methods). An abstract class may contain implemented methods. If you cannot remove these methods implementations (which seems likely), then you should keep it as is.

Comment: It's hard to say. You need to explore controller childern usage.

Comment: Exploring more as I go, I believe that the methods are allowing me to access the registry via `$this` from within the extended controllers. So I imagine it'll need to stay as is.

Comment: @VinceKronlein , your questions sounds like `I have application. Could I remove this methods?`

Comment: I think the smart solution would be to move those methods to the Front class, rename it Controller and remove the existing controller class altogether.  It seems pointless to have another class to load when all it's doing is accessing the registry object.  I can do that in the existing Front class.